A question about the eigenfunction method and the notion of solution - distributional solution
I have a question about how a passage was made in the calculation of passage (2.5) in the calculation below. To introduce context, the author in the paper (full work)  is trying to demonstrate that the Fujita critical exponent of the equation
$$\dfrac{du}{dt} - \Delta(u^m) = t^s|x|^{\sigma}u^p , \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T)$$
is $p_c = m+s(m-1)+(2+2s+\sigma)/n.$ It first studies the case $s=0$, according to the calculation in the image below. It essentially uses the test function method together with a differential inequality to study the blow-up. After defining $w_l(t)$ in (2.4) it performs the differentiation at $t$ to get (2.5)
$$ \dfrac{dw_l}{dt} =_\underbrace{?} \int_{\Omega} u_t \varphi_l dx=_\underbrace{?} \int_{\Omega}[\Delta(u^m) \varphi_l + |x|^{\sigma}u^p \varphi_l ]dx.$$
It was exactly this part in (2.5) that I didn't understand, it doesn't seem to be integration by parts or derivation in the sense of distributions.  Because $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_1$ if it were integration by parts, in the sense of the calculation I wrote above, boundary terms would appear $ \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \varphi_l  \nabla(u^m) \cdot \nu dS - \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} u^m \nabla \varphi_l \cdot \nu dS $ and the first one could be non-zero. Perhaps the author is considering this equation in the sense of distributions $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$
$$ \langle u_t, \varphi_l \rangle = \langle \Delta(u^m) , \varphi_l \rangle + \langle|x|^{\sigma}u^p ,\varphi_l \rangle , \quad \forall \varphi_l \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega).$$
This might justify moving the Laplacian to $\varphi_l$, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have any guesses? Thank you in advance, and below is the part of the paper that contains my question.

